# trouble with IndexOfMaxInRange

Tags: java, xcode

I'm posting only cause I have run into a wall with the code I'm writing.

The goal of the code is to sort the array from greatest to least using the swap and IndexOMaxInRange methods in the selectionSort method. I understand my code can be sloppy but I have really hit a wall with this one.

My question is:

why do i keep getting a "reached the end while parsing" error, it may be obvious but im not to keen with using return statements so that may be of help when trying to debug this but i am quite lost with it.

The error that i get back when i run the code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at indexofmaxinrange.IndexOfMaxInRange.selectionSort(IndexOfMaxInRange.java:27)
at indexofmaxinrange.IndexOfMaxInRange.main(IndexOfMaxInRange.java:36)
Java Result: 1

code:


package indexofmaxinrange;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
* @author zrcenivi
*/

public class IndexOfMaxInRange {
public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[]a){        
Arrays.sort(a);
int gindex = a.length - 1;
return gindex;
} 
public static int[] swapElement(int[]a2, int j, int i) {
int temp = i;
a2[i] = a2[j];
a2[j] = temp;
return a2;
}
public static int[] selectionSort(int[]a){
Arrays.sort(a);
int min=0; int temp;
for (int i=0;i<=a.length - 1;i++){
min = i;
}
for (int j = a.length; j >=0; j--){
if (a[min]<a[j]){
a = swapElement(a,a[min],a[j]);
}
}      
return a;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] A = {1,3,2};
System.out.println(selectionSort(A));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int j = a.length - 1; j >=0; j--) {
}
```

Instead of

```
for (int j = a.length; j >=0; j--){
}
```

Also, this will print what you expect

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] A = { 1, 3, 2 };
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionSort(A)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 places can cause Index Out of Range.

1
   `for (int **j = a.length**; j >=0; j--){`

The **max index** we can use is `a.length -1`. You should use

```
for (int j = a.length-1; j >=0; j--){
```

2 You should pass index to method swapElement, rather than the value in array with the index. It is because that the value might exceed the length of Array.

```
 if (a[min]<a[j]){

  a = swapElement(a,a[min],a[j]);
 }
```

Use the following code for instead.

```
 if (a[min] < a[j]) {
            a = swapElement(a, min, j);
        }
```

In addition. You can use `Arrays.toString` method to print the array content.

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionSort(A)));
```

text example is as follows:

```
int[] A = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 9, 25,12};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionSort(A)));
```

Output in console:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 25]
```